# Luhn Algorithm in C; problem debugging with atoi function

Tags: c, luhn

I'm having a problem with taking the individual characters in the string entered by the user and converting them into integers. I use XCode, and the error that pops up when I use atoi function is:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversation passing 'char' to the
> parameter of type 'const char *'

Then I take the address with `&`, and then it asks me to fix the issue by adding `&`. Whenever I do this, however, the debugging screen appears and I have no idea what to do from there.
Can somebody show me how to properly format this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char cardnumber[17];

    printf("Enter your card number: ");
    scanf("\n%s",cardnumber);
    
    int c;
    for (c=0; cardnumber[c]!='\0'; c++)
    {
        if (isdigit(cardnumber[c]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid Entry");
        }
    }
    
    int i=0;
    int odd1 = atoi(cardnumber[i]);
    int odd2 = atoi(cardnumber[i+2]);
    int odd3 = atoi(cardnumber[i+4]);
    int odd4 = atoi(cardnumber[i+6]);
    int odd5 = atoi(cardnumber[i+8]);
    int odd6 = atoi(cardnumber[i+10]);
    int odd7 = atoi(cardnumber[i+12]);
    int odd8 = atoi(cardnumber[i+14]);
    
    int s1 = odd1*2;
    int s2 = odd2*2;
    int s3 = odd3*2;
    int s4 = odd4*2;
    int s5 = odd5*2;
    int s6 = odd6*2;
    int s7 = odd7*2;
    int s8 = odd8*2;
    
    int t1 = ((s1/10)+(s1%10));
    int t2 = ((s2/10)+(s2%10));
    int t3 = ((s3/10)+(s3%10));
    int t4 = ((s4/10)+(s4%10));
    int t5 = ((s5/10)+(s5%10));
    int t6 = ((s6/10)+(s6%10));
    int t7 = ((s7/10)+(s7%10));
    int t8 = ((s8/10)+(s8%10));
    
    int even1 = atoi(cardnumber[i+1]);
    int even2 = atoi(cardnumber[i+3]);
    int even3 = atoi(cardnumber[i+5]);
    int even4 = atoi(cardnumber[i+7]);
    int even5 = atoi(cardnumber[i+9]);
    int even6 = atoi(cardnumber[i+11]);
    int even7 = atoi(cardnumber[i+13]);
    int checkdigit = atoi(cardnumber[i+15]);
    
    int check=((t1+t2+t3+t4+t5+t6+t7+t8+even1+even2+even3+even4+even5+even6+even7)%10);
    if(check==0)
    {
        if(check==checkdigit)
        {
            printf("Your card is accepted.");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid entry.\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(10-check==checkdigit)
        {
            printf("Your card is accepted.");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid entry.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `atoi` accepts a null-terminated string (`char *`), but `cardnumber[i]` and friends are individual characters

Comment: To convert a single character to a number, just use `cardnumber[i] - '0'`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your input is in ASCII, all digit characters have consecutive integer codes. So, once you tested with `isdigit()` all characters are actually digits, it's enough to subtract the code of character zero `'0'` from each digit to obtain their numerical values:

```
int odd1 = cardnumber[i] - '0';
int odd2 = cardnumber[i+2] - '0';
```

...and so on.

Comment: The C standard guarantees the digit codes are consecutive regardless of whether ASCII is used, in C 2018 5.2.1. 3.

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` should be passed a pointer to the first character of a string of characters.

`cardnumber` is an array of `char`. `cardnumber[i]` is a `char`. It is not a pointer. Therefore, `atoi(cardnumber[i])` does not pass a pointer to `atoi`.

To convert the character code for a digit to the number the digit represents, subtract the code for the character “0”:

```
int odd1 = cardnumber[i] - '0';
```

This works because the code numbers for digit characters are guarantee to be consecutive. So subtracting the code for “0” from the code for a digit yields the number the digit represents—0 for “0”, 1 for “1”, 2 for “2”, and so on.

Also be sure to test that the entered string contains only digits, and that at most 16 characters are read into `cardnumber`. Use `%16s` instead of `%s`.